# PHP $_SESSION Returning Empty Array Even When Values are Set

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to diagnose a PHP problem.  I'm passing values to a `$_SESSION` array, and those values are not taken by the array.  I used `var_dump($_SESSION)` to see what was being returned and I get `array (0){}`.  This is true even when I know the session is being set and values are being added to the array.

Here's a simplified version of my code (index.php):

```php
<?php
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION); 

if ($_REQUEST['query'] == "" or is_null($_REQUEST['query'])) {
$errormsg = "You must enter a search term to query.  Please try again.";
}

?>

<form name="product_search" id="product_search" method="post" action="index.php">
<input size="60" type="text" name="query" id="query" <?php echo "value=\"" .  $_REQUEST['query'] . "\" "; ?>/>
<?php if (isset($errormsg)) {echo "<span class=\"errormsg\">" . $errormsg . "</span>";} ?>
<input type="submit" class="searchBtn" value="Search"/>

<?php
    $_SESSION['query'] = 'foo';
    $_SESSION['search_field'] = 'man';
    $_SESSION['results'] = 'chu';
?>

var_dump($_SESSION); //Will dump array(3) {...}
```

To recreate error:

1. Load the page.  No problem here; `var_dump($_SESSION)` at the top returns `array(0) {}`, which is expected, and the one at the botton returns a three-member array, also as expected.
2. Submit the form with something in the query field (to defeat the validation).  Despite the `$_SESSION` variables being set on the previous page load, the first dump still returns `array(0) {}`.

I simplified my code here to get at the problem, but I have another page that is returning a $_SESSION variable without difficulty (and the first `var_dump` produces a one-member array).  Is the problem here that I'm submitting the form to itself, and if so, is there a way other than the `$_SESSION` array to pass values from one page load to the next?  I've looked at the PHP documentation and searched high and low, but haven't caught anything that's helped.

I should also note that the session ID is the same across page loads, so it appears session state is being maintained from page load to page load.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This code works fine in my environment. Can include some placeholders, if not the full complexity of your code?

Comment: Jeremy,

Sure.  Here's the whole thing:

Comment: It's possible your server is configured incorrectly - no writable access to the session folder?

Answer (score 7):

Use this row at the top of each webpage:

`if (!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }`

If you initialize `$_SESSION` into lower level script, then the `$_SESSION variable is not accessible in upper level.

Comment: There is never a need to conditionally call `session_start()`.  Unconditionally call it before doing anything on any of your pages where you need to maintain the session superglobal.

Answer (score 3):

session.cookie_secure = 1 may cause this issue

UPD: check session.cookie_secure is set to 0 for non-secure connection.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', '0')
```

Worked for me.

UPD: Similar question [PHP session.cookie_secure: Disables sessions when set to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047170/php-session-cookie-secure-disables-sessions-when-set-to-true)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I recently faced the same problem so I just share a possible solution. It answers the question above - why $_SESSION returns empty array

Comment: It worked for me, I've tried too many things, but this was the only one who worked, thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your server config allows session cookies.

```
session.use_cookies = 1
```

The alternative is that the session id is passed around in the GET, and you would have to specifically append it to your form action, which you aren't doing. Hence, no session once the values are posted.

Answer (score 0):

Are sessions properly enabled? Here is the documentation for the PHP server session settings
http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

To add to Jeremy's answer, you could also be denying cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SESSION You still can use a POST as You are using it anyway - simply pack the variables and their values to one (or more) hidden inputs (You can serialize the POST from one submit and insert it to a hidden input or You can create as much hidden inputs as much You have variables from first submit). Then in second submit (maybe a second step of multi-step form) You post new data and of course the data from the first submit...

But I still prefer session as it is easier (do not have to implement more code).

Are You sure that the SESSION is not regenerating at each page load/submit? If You regenerate a session ID at page load/submit the old session (with its data) is lost and the data are inserted under new session ID...

Also a recommendation: forget about the $_REQUEST unless You are sure it is totaly neccessary and rather use only $_GET or $_POST to obtain the data from the right channel...

Comment: He said in his question that the same session ID is persisting across page loads.

Comment: Thank all for your quick answers.  Jeremy and others....sorry for the trouble, but I realized my problem.  Instead of passing a string (like `chu` in the example above), I was passing an variable, which itself was of sufficient size to overflow the buffer on the server.  I didn't have access to the error logs, so the server admin confirmed it later.

Thanks for the follow-up!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late to the game, and it might be that nobody encounters this configuration issue. In fact, I hope not.

My web host just moved all my sites to a new server.  They royally messed up the file and directory permissions, along with the user that the webserver and php scripts are run as.

It seems that the

```
session.auto_start = 1
```

flag results in a different user (and I can't tell which) trying to read the session file than if I set it to 0 and just use

```
session_start();
```

in my scripts.

The amazing permissions issue is that the session file is written but can't be read.  So auto-starting sessions are always empty.