# PHP session.cookie_secure: Disables sessions when set to true

Tags: php, session

When I set the following config:

`ini_set("session.cookie_secure", 1);`

My whole application's session disables and I can no longer write to or read from session variables.

```
$sessionName = "us";
session_name($sessionName);
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.entropy_file', '/dev/urandom');
ini_set('session.hash_function', 'whirlpool');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
// ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
```

Is this config compatible with `session.cookie_secure`? PHP Manual doesn't seem to have explanation of all these configs. [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure)

Comment: Are you using http or https? if cookie_secure is set to 1 you can only use https

Comment: @raidenace The problem was that PHP Manual has only a line describing that config and I was tired of fixing that. I thought that only line won't explain the problem so, I posted it on SO. After Charlotte's answer, I reread the Manual seriously and came by this phrase: `over secure connections`

Comment: I know...the manuals can be cryptic at times and it is easy to overlook stuff! Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

session.cookie_secure specifies whether cookies should only be sent over secure connections (HTTPS). If you're using HTTP, you won't get any cookies from the server. That's why you don't have a session.

edit: I should be more accurate. You get the cookies, but your browser doesn't send them to the server, because you're not using a secure connection.

Comment: Oh man! You're right. I've wasted so much time on it. I had read that paragraph many times but I think I was tired fixing the problem and couldn't understand that it should be only turned on for HTTPS protocol. BTW, I am using HTTP. Thanks for the info. :D

Answer (score 2):

Setting **[session.cookie_secure](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure)** to true means that it will only send the session cookie over a secure connection aka (SSL)

If you aren't using SSL then you won't be sending the session cookie in your requests

Read the PHP manual about [session.cookie_secure](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure).