# PHP session is not working with Firefox

Tags: php, session, firefox

This happens only when I'm logging through with Firefox,
what is the reason for that and how can I make this session working in Firefox?

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $username=$_SESSION["username"];

    $sql="select * from person where username ='".$username."'";
```

Comment: session always store on server :)

Comment: A session identifier is stored in the browser. Take a look through your cookie and other settings.

Comment: What is the solution for that?

Comment: @Matt this happens when I'm acessing my app using firefox

Comment: @ruvi: Is it working fine in other browsers?

Comment: clear your all session browser and try again

Comment: which error do you get? are you sure the error is caused by session and not maybe your sql query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP $\_SESSION Returning Empty Array Even When Values are Set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519257/php-session-returning-empty-array-even-when-values-are-set)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems related to Cache.

Use below headers to remove cache issue. add it after `session_start()`.

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Hope it will help you :-)

Comment: yes it's working through the other browsers. I used above to lines but it's still not working