# PHP $_SESSION array is empty with frontend production build but NOT with developement build

Tags: php, apache, session, session-variables, webpack-dev-server

I have a backend hosted in `https://api.mydomain.abc`, and I'm developing a frontend with vue/quasar CLI that uses webpack server.

When the frontend is running in developement mode it's hosted by webpack web server, and the urls in the frontend code have `/api/index.php` format. Then the webpack server is configured to proxy them to the real backend url:

```
devServer: {
  ...,
  proxy: {
    // proxy all requests starting with /api to avoid cors problems.
    '/api': {
      target: 'https://api.mydomain.abc',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api': '' //remove /api from the final url
      }
    }
  }
},
```

When running in production mode the fronted is hosted by an NGINX server at `https://www.mydomain.abc` and the urls in the front end now are directly like `https://api.mydomain.abc`.

From now on, both request types (development and production) are the same. `https://api.mydomain.abc` requests are listened by the same NGINX server but now working as reverse proxy, that redirects them to an apache server with PHP mod. Here there is a very simple plain PHP script without any external framework or library, that simply manages login and return some dynamic values from DB if user is correctly logged.

The point is that in developement environment everything works flawlessly, but with the production environment all the login protected requests fails because $_SESSION array is empty!!

I'm completely clueless what could cause these kind of error, since the backend it's the same for both environments.

Further info:

- CORS headers are set in apache server to allow requests from [www.mydomain.abc](http://www.mydomain.abc) (and also mydomain.abc), and there aren't any CORS errors.
- Both environments access the backend with `https` protocol
- My PHP script runs `session_start()` unconditionally at the begining of the script

I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445005/10551132) but no changes have been observed.

What could cause this difference between both environments? They are practically the same apart from the webpack server.

Comment: Just double-check: Do you have directives in the webpack server to perform the proxy for the production server ?

Comment: Sorry @KenLee, I think I haven't undestood you correctly. Webpack server isn't involved when frontend it's hosted into production web server (NGINX).

Comment: NGINX doesn't handle the sessions. It's used as static web server for the front-end (when deployed in production mode) and as reverse proxy to the api web server (apache). Is apache the one that manages the sessions. The point is this is the same for both environments (dev & prod), both share the same reverse proxy and the same backend environment. The only difference is that in development mode, there is another proxy in top of everything, the webpack server, that somehow makes it different.

Comment: Have you checked in the Network tab of the developer tools that the session cookies are being sent?

Comment: oh i see. then it is very strange. because you have one layer less in production. Let me check the documentation to see whether there is any hint

Comment: @vstm: They are being sent: `Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=************; path=/`. @Ken Lee exactly...

Comment: Well that's the `Set-Cookie` header being sent from the server to the client. What about the `Cookie: ` header that should be sent from the client to the server?

Comment: @vstm Wow, of course my bad. But the point is that you are totally right, frontend is never returning the cookie to the server in production environment, but it's doing it in developement. As consequence the server is restarting the session in every request :S. I'm currently looking for further info about that.

Comment: What are you using to make requests, is it axios or are you using `fetch` directly? With fetch there's the `credentials` option, with axios there's `withCredentials`.

Comment: @vstm Yes, it was that. `credentials: "include"` made it for `fetch`. The problem wasn't triggered during development because it was a `same-origin` environment between frontend and backend instead of `cross-origin`. Nice to note also that header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "true"` needs to be set also into server side, if not CORS bites again. Thanks you all for your help. You can make an answer if you want and I will select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer it myself. The problem was that during development the browser was in localhost url, doing requests to a localhost server (the webpack server, than then was proxying it to the real api production server, but browser was unaware of that). It was a `same-origin` enviroment for the browser, so `fetch` API was sending the credentials (phpsessioncookie) to the server as it's the default behaviour in `same-origin` environments.

In production environment, the webpack server wasn't into the mix, and the browser was in `(www.)mydomain.com` doing requests to `api.mydomain.com`. The problem here is that even if `(www.)mydomain.com` was set as an allowed origin in the API web server, for the browser it was a `cross-origin` environment, which implies that the `fetch` API doesn't send the credentials by default. `credentials:include` overrides the default value and sends them.

Also the header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "true"` is needed in the server side if it wasn't present.